# window.google is undefined with Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization, angular-google-maps, angular-google-chart

I'm using angular-google-chart version 0.0.11 even i tried with 0.1.0 version

it always failed at

```
window.google.load('visualization', apiConfig.version, settings);
```

When I debug it, I found window.google is undefined

I also tried the below solution and that also did not work for me.

https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/issues/267

Could someone help me out.

Comment: Why should `window.google` be defined in the first place? What have you done to define it?

Comment: I'm using the angular-google-chart library and it's failing inside the library.

I just tried to customize the library multiple ways to get it done but did not worked

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your line inside **window.onload** to make sure the library is loaded.

```
window.onload = () => {
    window.google.load('visualization', apiConfig.version, settings);
}
```

Comment: It did not help